# Replace multiple characters from string without using any nested replace functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, replace

I have an equation stored in my table. I am fetching one equation at a time and want to replace all the operators with any other character.

**Input String:** `(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35`

**Operators or patterns:** `(+, -, *, /, %, (, ))`

**Replacement character:** `~`

**Output String:** `~N_100~~6858~~~6858~~N_100~0_2~~N_35`

I had tried below query with **Nested REPLACE** Functions and I got desired output:

```
DECLARE @NEWSTRING VARCHAR(100) 
SET @NEWSTRING = '(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35' ;
SELECT @NEWSTRING = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                    @NEWSTRING, '+', '~'), '-', '~'), '*', '~'), '/', '~')
                   , '%', '~'), '(', '~'), ')', '~')
PRINT @NEWSTRING
```

**Output:** `~N_100~~6858~~~6858~~N_100~0_2~~N_35`

How can I replace all the operators without using nested replace functions?

Comment: Why what is wrong with Multiple Replce functions ?

Comment: I have some other operators also and I have to write Replace function multiple times. So I am finding alternate way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had created a `SPLIT` function to implement this because I need to implement this operation multiple time in `PROCEDURE`

**SPLIT FUNCTION**

```
create function [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

**Code used in procedure:**

```
DECLARE @NEWSTRING VARCHAR(100) 
SET @NEWSTRING = '(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35' ;
SELECT @NEWSTRING = REPLACE(@NEWSTRING, items, '~') FROM dbo.Split('+,-,*,/,%,(,)', ',');
PRINT @NEWSTRING
```

**OUTPUT**

```
~N_100~~6858~~~6858~~N_100~0_2~~N_35
```

Comment: This is no need for a split function. The only purpose it is serving is to dynamically spit out a table. Since the replacement characters are a small, finite set, it is much much better to just create a temp table as shown in @Shane's answer. Also, there are many ways to accomplish a string split in T-SQL, and you have chosen the slowest. Please look into a SQLCLR-based splitter (you can get for free via [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com) (which I am the creator of but String_Split is in the Free version) or, at the very least, an XML-based splitter.

Comment: @srutzky Thank for your comment but I have to apply some business login on splitted values so I had used SPLIT function to split the values. So every time I can't use temporary table.

Comment: Ok about using split vs temp table. But, I am also saying to not use _that_ split function. Split functions based on WHILE loops are horribly inefficient. There are several better choices.

Comment: @srutzky Can you provide me the other way to write split function

Comment: I provided a link in my first comment to a free SQLCLR splitter. Or you can search the web for examples if you want to write your own.

Answer (score 12):

I believe it is easier and more readable if you use a table to drive this.

```
declare @String varchar(max) = '(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35'

--table containing values to be replaced
create table #Replace 
(
    StringToReplace varchar(100) not null primary key clustered
    ,ReplacementString varchar(100) not null    
)

insert into #Replace (StringToReplace, ReplacementString)
values ('+', '~')
    ,('-', '~')
    ,('*', '~')
    ,('/', '~')
    ,('%', '~')
    ,('(', '~')
    ,(')', '~')

select @String = replace(@String, StringToReplace, ReplacementString)
from #Replace a

select @String

drop table #Replace
```

Comment: This is definitely better than using a split function (and a horribly inefficient one at that) to spit out a table dynamically. It is also 1000 times better than a while loop using a WHILE loop and PATINDEX :). +1

Comment: @srutzky OR Shane Gebs, if you're out there -- I'd love to have something like this (running on a field from each row of a table variable rather than a scalar), but for some reason, it is only replacing the first pair of values (first row) of #Replace (?) ---- that is, I've got letter pairs `('a', '+a'), ('b','+b'),('c'`...etc and it's replacing all occurrences of `a` in the field of each row with `+a`, but not the `b` or `c`, etc replacements (?)

Comment: @CodeJockey Create a new question, reference this answer, and show what your current code is and the data you are trying to manipulate. Then post a link to that question here and I will answer it.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Hey ! I am trying to do exactly what CodeJockey asked for. Would you mind take a look at this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800289

Answer (score 5):

There is not equivalent for the TRANSLATE function from Oracle in SQL Server, you have to use nested replace functions.

The following solution is *technically* correct:

```
DECLARE @newstring VARCHAR(100) = '(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35';
DECLARE @pattern VARCHAR(100) = '%[+-\*/%()]%';
DECLARE @i INT;
BEGIN
  SET @i = PATINDEX(@pattern,@newstring) 
  WHILE @i <> 0
  BEGIN
    SET @newstring = LEFT(@newstring,@i-1) + '~' + SUBSTRING(@newstring,@i+1,100);
    SET @i = PATINDEX(@pattern,@newstring) 
  END
  SELECT @newstring;
END;
```

But I do not see why you would favor this over nested REPLACE calls.

Comment: I want alternative to do this operation.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use `TRANSLATE` function. It is availble from `SQL Server 2017 (aka vNext)` and above.

> [`TRANSLATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt775084.aspx)
>
> Returns the string provided as a first argument after some characters specified in the second argument are translated into a destination set of characters.
>
> ```
> TRANSLATE ( inputString, characters, translations)
> ```
>
> Returns a character expression of the same type as inputString where characters from the second argument are replaced with the matching characters from third argument.

In your case:

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35', '+-*/%()','~~~~~~~')
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be3e4f2e9a699663a3ea99cf397d3403)**

Answer (score 0):

you can replace all the operators without using nested replace functions

```
DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(300) ='%[+-\*/%()]%';
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(300) ='(N_100-(6858)*(6858)*N_100/0_2)%N_35';
WHILE PatIndex(@Pattern, @String) <> 0
    SELECT @String=Replace(@String, Substring(@String, PatIndex(@Pattern, @String), 1), '~')
SELECT @String
```