# Rewrite this exceedingly long query

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I just stumbled across this gem in our code:

```
my $str_rep="lower(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(field,'-',''),'',''),'.',''),'_',''),'+',''),',',''),':',''),';',''),'/',''),'|',''),'\',''),'*',''),'~','')) like lower('%var%')";
```

I'm not really an expert in DB, but I have a hunch it can be rewritten in a more sane manner. Can it?

Comment: What language is this in? What database? etc. We need more information.

Comment: You might be able to use [`SIMILAR TO`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-commons-predicates.html#fblangref25-commons-predsiimilarto) instead of all the replaces + like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the DBMS you are using. I'll post some examples (feel free to edit this answer to add more).

### MySQL

There is really not much to do; the only way to replace all the characters is nesting `REPLACE` functions as it has already been done in your code.

### Oracle DB

Your clause can be rewritten by using the [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions196.htm) function.

### SQL Server

Like in MySQL there aren't any functions similar to Oracle's `TRANSLATE`. I have found some (much longer) alternatives in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835090/replace-multiple-characters-from-string-without-using-any-nested-replace-functio). In general, however, queries become very long. I don't see any real advantages of doing so, besides having a more structured query that can be easily extended.

### Firebird

As suggested by Mark Rotteveel, you can use `SIMILAR TO` to rewrite the entire clause.

If you are allowed to build your query string via Perl you can also use a for loop against an array containing all the special characters.

**EDIT**: Sorry I did not see you indicated the DB in the tags. Consider only the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your flagged this as *Perl*, but it's probably not?

Here is a Perl solution anyway:

```
$var =~ s/[\-\.\_\+\,\:\;\/\|\\\*\~]+//g;
```

Comment: It's a part of a bigger SQL query, so your answer is incorrect. I'm Perl programmer, I would do something like that too, if it was the case. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I though so, but you tagged it as Perl and that's why I wrote a Perl answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know the languages concerned, but a couple of things come to mind.

Firstly you could look for a replace text function that does more that just a single character. Many languages have them. Some also do regular expression based find and replace.

Secondly the code looks like it is attempting to strip a specific list of characters. This list may not include all that is necessary which means a relatively high (pain in the butt) maintenance problem. A simpler solution might be to invert the problem and ask what characters do you want to keep? Inverting like this sometimes yields a simpler solution.