# How to make a nested replace of values from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with the following (dummy) structure:

```
Table 1
idText     sText(nvarchar(500))
1           Text with some keywords
2           Text2 with one keyword
3           Text3 with three keywords

Table 2 
idText    idKey    sKeyword  
1           1       some
1           2       keywords
2           3       one
3           4       with
3           2       keywords
3           5       three
```

Is there any way to execute a nested replace among all the related keywords from `Table2`?

There are some solutions around like creating a function, but I do not think is a good solution because this is not going to be reused anywhere else. I did try a recursive CTE as well but without success.

The result must be something like this:

```
Table 1
idText     sText(nvarchar(500))
1           Text with Replaced_some Replaced_keywords
2           Text2 with Replaced_one keyword
3           Text3 Replaced_with Replaced_three Replaced_keywords
```

PS.

- The *Replaced* string is fixed. So you can use the string you prefer. The Replace sentence would be something like this: `replace(sText, sKeyword, 'Replaced_' + sKeyowrd)`
- IdKey is useless in this case, however it is part of our real DB structure

This is my failed attemp using a recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(  ID int,   sText nvarchar(200))
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(  ID int,   sKeyword nvarchar(10))

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(1, 'Text with some keywords')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(2, 'Text2 with one keyword')
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES(3, 'Text3 with three keywords')

INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1, 'some')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(1, 'keywords')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(2, 'one')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(3, 'with')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(3, 'keywords')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES(3, 'three')

;WITH CTE AS(

SELECT ID, sText FROM @Table1 
UNION ALL
SELECT c.ID, CAST(REPLACE(sText, sKeyword, 'New_' + sKeyword) AS nvarchar(200))  FROM CTE c 
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = c.ID
) 
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

The result is an infinite loop, it does not stop.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Where does "Replaced_some" come from?   Is it in a table, or do you just add "Replaced_" before every keyword?   Please post your attempt to use a recursive CTE so we can debug it.

Comment: I think I can see what you will replace, but not what you will replace it *with*, which seems necessary to know for a solution.

Comment: what is idKey used for?

Comment: I edit the question in order to make it clearer. Thanks @KtX2SkD

Comment: Please also post your attempt to solve this and why it did not work.

Comment: I don't think unvoting  the question was necessary or useful. I did add the CTE  @TabAlleman

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Function slimmed down as promised, will update answer description accordingly in due time.*

Per my current understanding of your problem, I think I can apply to it a function I designed to solve a more complex problem I had recently. There might be other solutions, but most certainly others can & will propose them, so why don't I offer you something a little less to be offered.

**Be advised though, it was meant to address something more complex than yours** (*explained later*), and *right now* I sadly don't have time to slim it down, but I'll get to that probably tomorrow. I hope the comments help. Irregardless, **I'll summarize my function's objective for you:**

There's a table that contains what messages to find, and what to replace them with. The function will receive a text value as input, will use a cursor to loop said table, and for each record in said table it will check if input text contains something to replace, and replace if applicable.

Two things to note about the original objective. **First,** there's a nested loop to address the scenario where a certain keyword exists multiple times, hence requiring multiple replacements. **Second,** I had to also deal with wildcards, variable lengths, and whether or not the replacement flag is set in discussed table. These two things plus others are probably the reason you'll find lots of weird material flying around.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [JACKINABOX](@TextToUpdate varchar(30), @FilterId int)
RETURNS varchar(30) AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Keyword varchar(30)

    DECLARE LonelyCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT Keyword FROM ReplacementInformation WHERE Id = @FilterId

    OPEN LonelyCursor ; FETCH NEXT FROM LonelyCursor INTO @Keyword

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- While there still remains keywords to process.
    BEGIN
        WHILE 1 = 1 -- Not sure, but I think this nested loop can be unlooped if [FETCH NEXT] was cut & pasted to replace [BREAK].
        BEGIN
            IF(CHARINDEX(@Keyword, @TextToUpdate) = 0)
                BREAK -- If cannot find current keyword anymore, move on to next keyword.
            ELSE -- Otherwise, update text then check again for same keyword.
                SET @TextToUpdate = REPLACE(@TextToUpdate, @Keyword, CONCAT('Replaced_', @Keyword))
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM LonelyCursor INTO @Keyword
    END

    CLOSE LonelyCursor ; DEALLOCATE LonelyCursor

    RETURN @TextToUpdate

END
```

Comment: I appreciate your try, however a cursor is most of the time ia a bad choice. Moreover, I stated in the question I am looking for a solution without using a function.

Comment: @Ayorus, cleaned code as agreed. It's true that cursors are inefficient compared to most other things, but **they do shine and even required in some situations**. Whether or not this case is such, I can't surely tell, but a slow solution is better than none, and in my problem it was almost-instantaneous. I'd recommend for you to try it out and assess, especially I'm guessing it's almost ready-to-apply.

Comment: Also, @Ayorus, I assumed the **"*no function*" concern** was for development overhead, not a permissions restriction, which is why I presented my function. Nevertheless, I'm almost certain **it can be rewritten** to be used out of a function scope, even with a loop instead of a cursor. Wish I could review your CTE for you, but I was never good with CTEs.

Comment: I appreciate your comments and help. Thanks @KtX2SkD